# Elastic search bulk index with C# API

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I want to bulk index json records to elastic search with NEST or Elasticsearch.Net API

My json data is :

```
{"index":{"_index":"abc","_type":"abc","_id":1}},{"Name":"ApplicationFrameHost","CPU":1.25,"Company":null,"Product":null,"Path":null},{"index":{"_index":"abc","_type":"abc","_id":2}},{"Name":"Calculator","CPU":0.5,"Company":null,"Product":null,"Path":null},{"index":{"_index":"abc","_type":"abc","_id":3}},{"Name":"chrome","CPU":142.9375,"Company":null,"Product":null,"Path":null},{"index":{"_index":"abc","_type":"abc","_id":4}},{"Name":"chrome","CPU":3336.34375,"Company":null,"Product":null,"Path":null},{"index":{"_index":"abc","_type":"abc","_id":5}},{"Name":"chrome","CPU":7.1875,"Company":null,"Product":null,"Path":null}\n\n
```

my code:

```
 var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new 
 Uri("http://localhost:9200/"));
        
        var client2 = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
       var jsonPostData = new PostData<object>(myJson);
        var bulkRequestParameters = new BulkRequestParameters
        {

        };
  Func<BulkRequestParameters, BulkRequestParameters> convert = delegate 
  (BulkRequestParameters s)
        {
            s.ErrorTrace(true);
            
            return s.Refresh(Refresh.True); 
        };

        var response = client2.LowLevel.Bulk<VoidResponse>("abc", "abc", 
        jsonPostData, convert);
```

In the response elastic return success with no error but still, data is not available on elastic?

Debug info from elastic:Successful low level call on POST: /`abc/abc/_bulk?error_trace=true&refresh=true`

It would be very helpful if someone can provide any clue what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by modifying input JSON format after each record-set it does not requires comma:

```
{"index":{"_index":"abc","_type":"abc","_id":1}}{"Name":"ApplicationFrameHost","CPU":1.25,"Company":null,"Product":null,"Path":null}{"index":{"_index":"abc","_type":"abc","_id":2}},{"Name":"audiodg","CPU":1.5625,"Company":null,"Product":null,"Path":null}{"index":{"_index":"abc","_type":"abc","_id":3}},{"Name":"Calculator","CPU":0.5,"Company":null,"Product":null,"Path":null}{"index":{"_index":"abc","_type":"abc","_id":4}},{"Name":"chrome","CPU":144.109375,"Company":null,"Product":null,"Path":null}{"index":{"_index":"abc","_type":"abc","_id":5}},{"Name":"chrome","CPU":3384.609375,"Company":null,"Product":null,"Path":null}
```